# Shortcuts with alt key do not work

Tags: keyboard, 18.10, shortcuts

After Ubuntu last update by "software & updates", I can't use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>ArrowKey</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>ArrowKey</kbd>. I used that shortcut for IDE navigation, since last system update it doesn't work.

When I try to map shortcut in IDE and press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow</kbd> it mapped like <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow</kbd> depends on which of <kbd>alt</kbd> or <kbd>shift</kbd> key was pressed first.

So it seems like the system blocks <kbd>alt</kbd>+ combination. Does anyone know where can I setup this, or how can I allow <kbd>alt</kbd>+ combination, because I can't find any similar in default keyboard settings.

Comment: Can you please specify what do you mean with "last update". From Ubuntu 18.04 -> 19.04, last `apt get update`? Maybe the name of the updated package(s)

Comment: by `last update` I mean some updates that downloaded by "software & updates". like daily updates.